# How to show specific JSON data using filter or other JS method (by attribute)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filter

Here is my JSON from an API request:

```
[ { name: 'PM1', value: 21.51, key: 'PM1' },
{ name: 'PM25', value: 35.08, key: 'PM25' },
{ name: 'PM10', value: 54.85, key: 'PM10' },
{ name: 'PRESSURE', value: 1021.45, key: 'PRESSURE' },
{ name: 'HUMIDITY', value: 97, key: 'HUMIDITY' },
{ name: 'TEMPERATURE', value: 10.4, key: 'TEMPERATURE' } ]
```

I want to remove the last 3 objects (`TEMPERATURE`, `PRESSURE` and `HUMIDITY`), so it would look like this:

```
[ { name: 'PM1', value: 21.51, key: 'PM1' },
{ name: 'PM25', value: 35.08, key: 'PM25' },
{ name: 'PM10', value: 54.85, key: 'PM10' } ]
```

The question is - what should I do? Using `slice()` is not a good option since sometimes objects might not be the same, for example, there might be no `TEMPERATURE` or `PRESSURE`. I hope I made myself clear. In case you asked, this data is going to be displayed to the user in a CLI app ;)

Comment: so is it always just the last three you want to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check the index. The snippet below will remove the last three items, as I believe this is what you want.

```js
const data = [ 
{ name: 'PM1', value: 21.51, key: 'PM1' },
{ name: 'PM25', value: 35.08, key: 'PM25' },
{ name: 'PM10', value: 54.85, key: 'PM10' },
{ name: 'PRESSURE', value: 1021.45, key: 'PRESSURE' },
{ name: 'HUMIDITY', value: 97, key: 'HUMIDITY' },
{ name: 'TEMPERATURE', value: 10.4, key: 'TEMPERATURE' } 
]

const newData = data.filter((item, index) => {
  if(index < data.length - 3) {
    return item;
  }
})

console.log(newData);
```

If you want to always keep `PM1`, `PM25` and `PM10` use the following:

```js
const data = [ 
{ name: 'PM1', value: 21.51, key: 'PM1' },
{ name: 'PM25', value: 35.08, key: 'PM25' },
{ name: 'PM10', value: 54.85, key: 'PM10' },
{ name: 'PRESSURE', value: 1021.45, key: 'PRESSURE' },
{ name: 'HUMIDITY', value: 97, key: 'HUMIDITY' },
{ name: 'TEMPERATURE', value: 10.4, key: 'TEMPERATURE' } 
]

newData = data.filter(item => (
  item.name == 'PM1' || item.name =='PM25' || item.name == 'PM10'
));

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: You beat me to it :-)

Comment: haha, it was neck and neck.  I have just been trying to get to 5,000 points. I can relax now :-D

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to exclude items whose names are not in `['TEMPERATURE', 'HUMIDITY', 'PRESSURE']`:

```js
var data = [{ name: 'PM1', value: 21.51, key: 'PM1' },
            { name: 'PM25', value: 35.08, key: 'PM25' },
            { name: 'PM10', value: 54.85, key: 'PM10' },
            { name: 'PRESSURE', value: 1021.45, key: 'PRESSURE' },
            { name: 'HUMIDITY', value: 97, key: 'HUMIDITY' },
            { name: 'TEMPERATURE', value: 10.4, key: 'TEMPERATURE' }];

console.log(data.filter(d => !['TEMPERATURE', 'HUMIDITY', 'PRESSURE'].includes(d.name)));
```